# android, how to send username and password to webservice as header fields?

Tags: android, http-headers, httpclient, httpurlconnection

i am trying to create an application on android phone that takes username and password from user, encrypt the password using md5 then connect to url with these parameters.

a code to connect worked fine on iphone, but i couldn't find something like it in android:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[request addValue:usernameField.text forHTTPHeaderField:@"UserName"];

[request addValue:MD5Pass2 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Password"];
```

i tried to connect via httpurlconnection used post/get Dataoutputstream, httpclient send parameters httpget/httppost, but no success.

I think I need to send the parameters as headerfield but I don't know how.

note: I compared encryption results and it was correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the Apache library to be much more straightforward when it comes to HTTP.

An example of this would be as follows:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
request.setURI(new URI("http://www.internet.com/api"));
```

Normally with a GET request you would use GET parameters, ie append them to the end of the URL like so:

```
String url = "http://www.internet.com/api?UserName=YourUsername&Password=yourpassword" 
request.setURI(new URI(url));
```

But since you specified you want them as headers you could:

```
request.addHeader("UserName", username);
request.addHeader("Password", password);
```

and then:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
//Parse the response from the input stream object inside the HttpResponse
```

Comment: thank you, your answer is clear and comprehensive, i tried it, and although i thought it will work (theoretically it must) but it did not, i am still getting the same result "login failed"!

Comment: at last i found the bug, they gave me a wrong username! now it is working, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using HttpUrlConnection with this http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#addRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: thank you for answering, i tried your solution but it gives the same result as before! "login failed" although i am sure that the parameters are correct!

Comment: it is working now fine, after correcting the data, thank you.